# SQL injection into LIMIT in MySQL 8

Tags: web-application, sql-injection, mysql

Given a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM users limit 1,$limit
```

Is there a way to exploit this when using MySQL 8 and the standard PHP MySQL functions (ie no `multi_query`)?

What I have tried (unsuccessfully):

- `1 procedure analyse(extractvalue [...]`
- `1 union select [...]`
- `ascii(substr((Select version()),1,1))`
- `(select 1)`
- `sleep(5)`

Comment: What about ;SELECT * FROM users?

Comment: @A.Darwin That's a good idea, but it only works with `multi_query` (which nobody really uses; at least, I haven't seen it yet).